# Wait for CSS property

Tags: css, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a problem with checking CSS properties in a Testcafe session.
I have a progres bar on the site with the html:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
```

When the operation is ready, this progress ba becomes a width of 100%.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

In my code I use now the line

```
await t.expect(Selector('.progress-bar.progress-bar-success').getStyleProperty('width')).eql('100%', {timeout: 90000})
```

But it will not work. It waits the whole time until the waiting time has finished.

I use a similar function inside another run, where I wait for changing the color of an item with CSS and RGB, this works perfectly.
I think now the problem is, that the style is not available on startup. Or is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because according to the [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes) the `getStyleProperty` method returns the computed value of width, which means that the value is returned in pixels, while you want to check the value in percents.

As a solution, I recommend you use the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism, which allows you to get the desired value.

I prepared a sample for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .bar {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .progress {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress" style="width: 0;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        var progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

        progress.style.width = Math.min(100, parseInt(progress.style.width) + 1) + '%';
    }, 50);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the test code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `progress`
    .page `index.html`;

const getStyleWidthInPercents = ClientFunction(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.progress').style.width;
});

test('progress', async t => {
    await t.expect(getStyleWidthInPercents()).eql('100%', {timeout: 90000})
});
```

Comment: Many thanks fr your tip. I did not recognized the value is in pixel.